# call of a class dynamically?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to create a dynamic call to intent?
I want to dynamically push a string variable called mIntent into an intent call..  is it possible:

```
Intent newView = new Intent(getContext(), mIntent);

                    newView.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    getContext().startActivity(newView)
```

my solution where "mIntent" is a string:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.slcinstore2","com.lcinstore2."+mIntent));
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    getContext().startActivity(i);
```

doing that and then adding it to my manifest works!

Comment: Your question is unclear ,,where you push  `string variable` ?

Comment: What is the type of `mIntent`? What do you want to do with in the activity you're calling?

Comment: mIntent is a string i got from a database.. i want it to be my class name and launch the new intent

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit unclear, but maybe I still understand what you are trying to do. 
You Intent should look like this :

```
 String clsName = "com.foo.bar.myClass";  // fully qualified name

 Intent newView = new Intent(getContext(), Class.forName(clsName));
 ....
 ....
 startActivity(newView);
```

This might be what your thinking of .... I havnt tested this so I dont know if it will actually work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Class.forName() and use getPackageName() to avoid hardcoding:

```
Intent newView = new Intent(getContext(), Class.forName(getPackageName() + "YourClassName"));
startActivity(newView);
```